# Is curator's persistent ephemeral nodes just regular ephemeral with retries?

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system, apache-curator

I'm new to curator and zk - and wanted to double check my understanding with the rest of the community. It seems that documentation for curator is not that well covered.

Are curator's persistent ephemeral nodes basically ephemeral znodes, but have extra mechanisms to re-establish connections once it's disconnected? Are there any other differences that are not obvious?

p.s. is there a community/discussion group for zk (or even better yet, curator)? A simple google search did not turn up anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PersistentEphemeralNode recipe makes sure that a specified EPHEMERAL node exists even if there is a server partition, etc. The recipe creates the node internally, monitors the connection and recreates the node if it gets deleted due to connection instability.

The Apache Curator website - http://curator.apache.org/ - has documentation. It also lists the mailing lists for Curator: http://curator.apache.org/mail-lists.html

NOTE: I'm the main author of Curator